# How work with instagram API?

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I start use Instagram API. I want to get all photos from one tag.
For this I use such api link:

```
http.api.instagram.com/v1/tags/test/media/recent&access_token=...
```

In result I have such response in JSON:

```
    {
  "pagination": {
    "next_min_id": "AQDPw33Vz6ZgxgHuZ8umA1c_Xavrys6Vuj61KqoUvr54ADSI7LKvBcx_MecQgyvaR-JrhO_s5DUAgkjFzHrGLidBZPUhxU4zi6iaNA1UeWQJVA",
    "min_tag_id": "AQDPw33Vz6ZgxgHuZ8umA1c_XavryJ6Vuj61KqoasdADSI7LKvBcx_MecQgyvaR-JrhO_s5DUAgkjFzHrGLidBZPzxcU4zi6iaNA1UeWQJVA",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1626816542803445150_32412343357",
      "user": {
        "id": "3241233357",
        "full_name": "test",
        "profile_picture": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/1626816542803445150_32412343357_a.jpg",
        "username": "test_software"
      },
      "images": {
        "thumbnail": {
          "width": 150,
          "height": 150,
          "url": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s150x150\/e35\/1626816542803445150_32412343357.jpg"
        },
        "low_resolution": {
          "width": 320,
          "height": 320,
          "url": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s320x320\/e35\/1626816542803445150_32412343357.jpg"
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
          "width": 640,
          "height": 640,
          "url": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s640x640\/sh0.08\/e35\/1626816542803445150_32412343357.jpg"
        }
      },
      "created_time": "141151666",
      "caption": {
        "id": "17879771646166136",
        "text": "#test",
        "created_time": "1508666666",
        "from": {
          "id": "3249481157",
          "full_name": "test",
          "profile_picture": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/1626816542803445150_32412343357.jpg",
          "username": "test_software"
        }
      },
      "user_has_liked": false,
      "likes": {
        "count": 1
      },
      "tags": [
        "test"
      ],
      "filter": "Moon",
      "comments": {
        "count": 0
      },
      "type": "image",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/BaTn124h0We\/",
      "location": null,
      "attribution": null,
      "users_in_photo": [

      ]
    },
   ....
  ],
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

How correct parse all data?

Instagram get JSON with 15 posts per page.

How get next 15 posts after parsing current 15 posts?

If I understand I must parse field `next_mid_id` and send next response with this field. It's correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to retrieve the content of the feed and then use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the string returned from the feed into an object.

```
$json_source = file_get_contents('http.api.instagram.com/v1/tags/test...');

$json_data = json_decode($json_source);

var_dump($json_data);
```